# Mongodb restrict to given IP to localhost

Tags: mongodb, localhost

I am trying to restrict the mongodb to local ip, it is not working.

Using MongoDb 3.2 version.
Below is the configuration file for the service, which is located in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\mongod.cfg"

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\mongo.log
    quiet: false
    logAppend: true
storage:
    dbPath: C:\data\db
    directoryPerDB: true
    wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
            cacheSizeGB: 2
            directoryForIndexes: true
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: [127.0.0.0, 10.64.87.231]
replication:
    oplogSizeMB: 500
    replSetName: "mongoDbRepSet"
setParameter:
    enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
processManagement:
    windowsService:
        serviceName: "MongoDB"
        displayName: "MongoDB 3.2 Standard"
        description: "This is the service for MongoDB 3.2 Standard version"
```

I am using below command

```
mongod --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\mongod.cfg" --install
```

I am restarting the mongo service after installing it with the configuraiton.

Strange thing is, when I open in RoboMongo and try to connect using `127.0.0.0` and `10.64.87.231` it is not working.

Also noticed that, it is connecting with ip addresses `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.255` (so many loopback ips?)

I also checked by assigning `enableLocalhostAuthBypass: true` but still not working.

What is wrong happening no idea. Please help me to restrict mongo service to give ip address.

Comment: The localhost address is `127.0.0.1`; you need to use this in your `bindIp` directive as well. `127.0.0.0` is a network address and not a usable host IP. If you are unable to connect, a useful starting point for errors is reviewing the MongoDB log file to make sure the server started successfully. I would then try connecting with the `mongo` shell before using third party tools. If the server is running and you can connect with the `mongo` shell, the next step would be updating your question with the exact error message and steps you are taking when the connection is not working.

Comment: @Stennie, ok so I need to drop 127.0.0.0, and use 127.0.0.1. But since I have not used the configuration of 127.0.0.1, but still all 127.0.x.x could able to access, I just wondered. Also I came to know that the ip address 10.64.87.231 is not free static ip in my LAN, I have requested new one, will check with that. and Yes I checked it has restarted successfully. and mongo shell was working fine with the address.